# Why is ON DELETE CASCADE declared on child tables instead of their parent?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

If a parent table has multiple child tables, wouldn't it make more sense to declare `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the parent table? This way, it wouldn't be necessary to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` on each of the child tables.

Comment: How is a parent table supposed to "know" when new child tables are defined?

Answer (score 1):

First -- and obviously -- you might not want `on delete cascade` on all foreign key relationships. Each foreign key can have its own behavior, which is defined where the foreign key is defined.

Also very important. The deletion behavior is assigned on the attribute associated with the table where the deletion is going to occur. That is much more in the spirit of SQL -- and sanity -- than having a master table decide to just delete records in a bunch of other tables.